# The space of Fredholm operators as a classifying space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, index-theory

Is it true that the space of Fredholm operators on a separable Hilbert space is the classifying space for K-theory in the category of paracompact spaces?

Everyone quotes the theorem of Atiyah-Janich in Atiyah's book - for example in the discussion [Homotopy groups of Fredholm operators](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178872/homotopy-groups-of-fredholm-operators).

However, this theorem that $[X,\mathcal{F}] = K(X)$ is stated for **compact** spaces $X.$ Does the same hold for paracompact $X?$ Any $X?$

Comment: What is your definition of $K$-theory for a noncompact space?

Comment: Usually $K$-theory is defined for a CW-complex as the inverse limit of $K$-theories of its finite subcomplexes. This makes what you ask essentially a tautology.

Comment: What if I take the definition to be the one in Atiyah's book? Simply the Grothendieck group of $Vect(X)$ with addition.

Comment: That definition doesn't give you a cohomology theory (it fails to satisfy the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms), so it cannot be representable. In particular it fails to satisfy the product axiom.

Comment: In fact as far as I can tell Atiyah in  his book defines K-theory only for compact topological spaces. For instance the crucial corollary 1.4.14 is *false* over a noncompact space.

Comment: @user58951: The correct definition of K-theory for paracompact spaces requires you to sheafify the presheaf of formal differences of vector bundles.  The point here is that as you move to infinity you might need formal differences of vector bundles whose dimension increases indefinitely.  For compact spaces this is unnecessary because you can choose a finite cover such that for each element of this cover you have an honest difference of vector bundles and because there are only finitely many of these, you can glue them together in a single difference.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Thank you, that sounds interesting. Can you suggest some reference? Do I understand correctly that this is what $\mathcal{F}$ classifies?

Comment: @user58951: Yes, these objects are classified by F.  See, for example, Section 3.1 in arXiv:0712.0702.